# Масштабирование сервиса. nginx, node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, vps

Какие правильные практики масштабирование бывают?
Допустим у меня есть

1. rest-сервер на node.js
2. сервер для рендера фронтенда десктопной версии сайта (node.js)
3. сервер для рендера мобильной версии (node.js)

Сейчас все довольно тупо и просто, у каждого сервера поднято по одному кластеру через pm2  и сверху nginx, который в зависимости от запроса проксирует его на нужный порт или отдает нужную статику для каждой версии.

Все запущено на одной ВМ.

1. Но вопрос в том, как правильно такие вещи масштабировать?
2. Какой идеальный и не очень варианты бывают?
3. Можно ли сделать одну ВМ, с поднятой на ней nginx и с неё проксировать на три разные ВМ? Но тогда получается статика будет отдаваться не так быстро, ведь запрос сначала будет проксироваться на сервер со статикой.

Зарание спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много. Идеально на все случаи жизни нет.

Часто статику выкладывают на отдельный домен.

Или можно держать статику вместе с nginx.